# Failing with simple CalendarApp script

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

Complete rookie here. Trying to implement a script that reads dates from Sheet and create events in Calendar. Starting from the very basics, but failing even to get the below going. When running the script not errors are given but the event is not written in Calendar.

Code below. Any thoughts?

function niccal() {
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("5jl5pm0c2k4i9iuhu5m9dkr37c@group.calendar.google.com").createAllDayEvent('Apollo', new Date('July 20, 2022'));
}

Comment: The code above works for me when replicating using a newly created calendar, perhaps can you share a bit more details regarding the calendar that you are trying to modify? Do you currently have permissions to make changes to events on the said calendar?

Comment: Thanks Diego for your help. Means a lot to be helped in these first stpes of mine into coding! So, that is a calendar I have created specifically for this. Brand new! I am the owner of the calendar. I have created the script in App Script with the same user that ownes the calendar. I wonder if I missing some basic steps in the set up etc?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, seems all good to me. Here is my calendar when I ran the script. https://imgur.com/a/OR276al, it shows two events because I tried a calendar that I created and a shared calendar, and both work fine as long as the calendarID is correct.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Do you know if there is anything I need to set in AppScript before the code can be run? I am completely new to that.

Comment: Should be straight forward, just run the script and the OAuth window should pop up for authorization first and run the script again. If that doesn't work, consider checking if pop ups are disabled for your browser. You can try to run the script again in a different script file, or do basic browser troubleshooting (try in an incognito window, check if extensions are messing up, uninstall-reinstall chrome browser, etc.)